# What happens if threading.stack_size() is used to set stack size beyond the allocated stack size for python application?

Tags: python

The stack size limit on python application on my system is 
limit
stacksize    40960 kbytes.
If threading.stack_size() is used to set the thread stack size to a value higher than 40960KB, will the stack size allocated to python application increase automatically?

Thanks

Comment: What stops you from trying?

Answer (score 1):

`threading.stack_size` sets or retrieves the stack size allocated for *new* threads. It cannot resize the stack for existing threads.

If your system has a default stack size of 40960 KB, that doesn't matter. `threading.stack_size` will override the default. That's the point.

If your system has a hard cap of 40960 KB for stack sizes, `threading.stack_size` will raise a `ValueError` on attempts to set a bigger stack size than that.

Comment: Thank you. Got the answer I was looking for.